# How do I insert a value into the search input of an Iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, iframe, pug

I have made a simple website with node and a pug page and I added an Iframe of wikipedia.com. I basically want to set the search input of wikipedia from the iframe with a value set by a button from the same pug page. Is it possible?

```html
<input id="searchInput" name="search" type="search" size="20" autofocus="autofocus" accesskey="F" dir="auto" autocomplete="off" style="padding-right: 64px;">
```

this is the input in the wikipedia iframe. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will not let you access the contents of an iframe if its source is an external server you do not have access to (see [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)).

Though you can display a result page from the wikipedia site, please see snippet below :

```js
function search(){
  const frames = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')
  if(frames.length > 0)
    frames[0].remove();
  const result = document.getElementById('result');
  const value = document.getElementById('input').value;
  const iframe =  document.createElement('iframe');
  const URL = `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=${value}&title=Special:Search&profile=advanced&fulltext=1&ns0=1`;
  result.appendChild(iframe)
  iframe.setAttribute('src', URL);

}
```

```css
#result{
  width:100%
}
iframe{
  width:100%;
  height:450px;
}
```

```html
<input value="Charles De Gaulle" type="search" id="input" placeholder="search">
<button onclick="search()" id="btn">Search</button>
<br><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

EDIT : You asked in the comment how to display the autocomplete suggestions that are displayed on the wikipedia website. To do this, you will need to add a backup script. I used PHP in my example, please [check the demo to see it working](https://www.lucasroquilly.com/stack_overflow_samples/wikipedia_autosuggest/) and check the snippets below :

JavaScript below

```
function search(){
        let input = document.getElementById('input');
        let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
        let res = document.getElementById('result');
        if(input.value.length < 3){
            res.innerHTML = "";
            return }
        fetch('api.php?str='+input.value)
        .then(function(response) {
            return (response.text());
        })
        .then(function(obj) {
            res.innerHTML = "";
            let arr = JSON.parse(obj);
            console.log(arr)
            for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(arr)) {
                let title = value.title;
                let url = value.fullurl;
                let img = typeof value.thumbnail == "undefined" ? null : value.thumbnail.source
                res.innerHTML += 
                    img == null ? 
                    `<p><a href="${url}" target="_blank"><img width=64 height=64 style="background-color:grey">${title}</a></p>`
                    : 
                    `<p><a href="${url}" target="_blank"><img width=64 height=64 style="object-fit:cover" src="${img}">${title}</a></p>`
                
            }
        });

    }
```

CSS below

```
p > a{
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
    }
    img{
        margin-right:2em;
    }
```

HTML below

```
<input onkeyup="search()" value="" type="search" id="input" placeholder="search">
<button  id="btn">Search</button>
<br><br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

`api.php` PHP code below

```
<?php 

$str = rawurlencode($_GET["str"]);
if(!isset($str)||$str=='') exit();
$content=file_get_contents("https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&generator=prefixsearch&prop=image%7Cinfo%7Cpageprops%7Cpageimages%7Cdescription&redirects=&ppprop=displaytitle&piprop=thumbnail&pithumbsize=80&pilimit=6&gpssearch=".$str."&gpsnamespace=0&gpslimit=6&inprop=url");
$data=json_decode($content);
echo json_encode($data->query->pages);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is nice and almost what I am looking for, do you think there is a way to actually see the result in real time? Like instead of seeing the search results in an Iframe to actually see the ajax suggestions as if I just typed the value but I didn't submit it yet? Like this: https://imgur.com/gallery/jqXRGMz

Comment: @AdrianBenzo I think it is possible, let me check and edit my answer

Comment: Si vous êtes français, merci aussi dans votre langue, j'ai essayé d'apprendre la langue pendant plusieurs mois, j'ai trouvé intéressant que vous recherchiez le général De Gaulle, il est souvent mentionné dans les documentaires français !

Comment: @AdrianBenzo your french is great, thank you for the effort  You cannot do what you asked only on client side because of CORS. You will need a back-end script. I updated my answer with an example in PHP, with code and working live demo. This will not be hard to adapt in NodeJS, but it was easier to give you the example in PHP because I have a PHP server to host StackOverflow examples. Please upvote if that was useful 